# Changing bootstrap icon position when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

First, I'm very new to bootstrap so try to bear with me on this one. I've been working on a website that has a bootstrap sidebar I'm trying to get working right. I've seen other examples of this but I'm not sure what to do.

On the sidebar, I am using an `<i>` element icon before each item which in this case is `toggle icon-chevron-right`. What I would like to do is when someone clicks on an item on the sidebar, revealing the sub-items, the icon will change to toggle `icon-chevron-right` to `toggle icon-chevron-down`.

I have played around with some JavaScript trying to get it working but to no avail. Any insights would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the class on the icon, when the `<a>` clicked:

```
$('a').click(function () {
   var icon = $(this).find('i');
   if (icon.hasClass('icon-chevron-down')) {
      icon.removeClass('icon-chevron-down').addClass('icon-chevron-right');
   }
   else {
      icon.removeClass('icon-chevron-right').addClass('icon-chevron-down')
   }
});
```

Comment: That did it! I guess it was as easy as replacing the class. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a sprite with both your right and down arrows in then use CSS to toggle between the two by adjusting the background position.

Like:

```
element {
    background: url(images/whatever.png) no-repeat;
}

 element:active {
    background: url(images/whatever.png) no-repeat 10px 10px;
}
```

play around with the position until you have it right